# ErrorException JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle

Tags: macos, symfony, osx-lion

I am trying to install vendors for the following project [connect](https://github.com/dsyph3r/connect) on osx lion.

```
cd /tmp
git clone git://github.com/dsyph3r/connect
cd connect
git submodule update --init

php bin/vendors install
```

When I run the following command `php bin/vendors install` I get the following messages:

```
[ErrorException]

Catchable Fatal Error:
Argument 1 passed to JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle::__construct()
must implement interface Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelInterface, 
none given, called in /Users/antoniopierro/Sites/connect/app/AppKernel.php on line 21
and defined in /Users/antoniopierro/Sites/connect/vendor/bundles/JMS/SerializerBundle/JMSSerializerBundle.php line 37
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass the kernel to the bundle's constructor:

```
$bundles = array(
    //...
    new JMS\SerializerBundle\JMSSerializerBundle($this),
    //...
);
```

Comment: This project is 7 months old, that why it does not work : JMSSerializerBundle's code has changed

Comment: @greg0ire @elnur, thanks for your answers. Now it works but I get another problem related to `app/config/parameters.ini`, please see the following question: [Fatal error: Class 'FOS\Rest\Util\Codes' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10370883/fatal-error-class-fos-rest-util-codes-not-found)