# Fatal error: Class 'FOS\Rest\Util\Codes' not found

Tags: php, macos, symfony

I am trying to install the following project [connect](https://github.com/dsyph3r/connect) on osx lion.

```
cd /tmp
git clone git://github.com/dsyph3r/connect
cd connect
git submodule update --init

php bin/vendors install
```

When I run the following command `php bin/vendors install` I get the following messages:

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                                
Cannot import resource "parameters.ini" from "/private/tmp/connect/app/config/config.yml".
```

In order to fix the following error I did:

```
     cp app/config/parameters.ini.dist app/config/parameters.ini
```

Then when I run the following command `php bin/vendors install` I get the following error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FOS\Rest\Util\Codes' not found in /private/tmp/connect/vendor/bundles/FOS/RestBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php on line 115

Fatal error: Class 'FOS\Rest\Util\Codes' not found in /private/tmp/connect/vendor/bundles/FOS/RestBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php on line 115
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'FOS\Rest\Util\Codes' not found in /private/tmp/connect/vendor/bundles/FOS/RestBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php on line 115

Fatal error: Class 'FOS\Rest\Util\Codes' not found in /private/tmp/connect/vendor/bundles/FOS/RestBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php on line 115
```

What did I miss?

I suppose now the problem is in my `app/config/parameters.ini`.
How should it be?

Answer (score 1):

There is an entry in the deps file for the FOSRestBundle, but not for the FOSRest library.
Look at the [FOSRestBundle installation documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/1-setting_up_the_bundle.md), it shows how the deps file should look like. I guess this was one project 7 months ago, and it must have split after.

Comment: the deps file is at the root of your project. It lists its external dependencies.

Comment: Don't forget to setup the autoloader for the library (step B in the documentation link above)